# Magento 2: How to call dynamic data/ phtml file content on confirmation widget calling on massaction on sales order grid

Tags: magento2

> Have added an massaction on sales order grid and want to open a modal
>   popup while clicking on massaction and on popup wants to display
>   dynamic data/form which value i have sent to controller after clicking
>   OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="switch_order_owner">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">switch_order_owner</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Switch Order Owner</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="switchorderowner/order/switchOrderOwner"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                              <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Switch Owner Confirmation</item>
                              <item name="template" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento version 2.1.2

Comment: have you found any solution