# Magento 2: How to open form in modal popup in your custom UI component

Tags: magento2

Below is my custom UI Component. Here in i want to open form on modal popup with custom field and want to save them.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'mage/translate'    
], function (Component,modal, confirm, $t) {
    'use strict';


     return Component.extend({


        myFunction: function () {
            modal({
                'title': 'Test Title',
                'autoOpen':true,
                'content':'how to pass Dynamic content'
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Did you check this? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128203/45181

Comment: Yes i've checked my UI component is JS file there they have used phtml file as well. And this functionality i have to integrate on sale order grid's massaction. Please see below link:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154023/magento-2-how-to-call-dynamic-data-phtml-file-content-on-confirmation-widget-c

Comment: Do your modal window appear on the page?

Comment: Yes Max, my modal is coming